# Create image effect in Cycles as FNAF / video noise effect

Tags: rendering, texturing, compositing-nodes

How can I create a camera effect as in FNAF?

[image: I mean the white lines, not the user interface]

Notice the white lines, not the user interface. Also, the black illumination, but explaining it separately.

Comment: What do you mean with "black illumniation"?
And does the animation effect "move" or is this a static image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do this effect in compositing by adding a noise texture. Create a noise texture and play with the settings until you have something you like. You probably will want to stretch it in X direction a good amount, otherwise you'll get boring TV noise...

To mix the texture with the render output, you could add them together. Also try a color mix node between the render and white with the (inverted) noise image as factor.

If compositing doesn't work, put the texture on a plane and attach it in front of the camera. In the material of that plane, the black of the texture should get transparent.

To animate it, animate either the seed or the UV coordinates.

**EDIT**

Just tried it out myself by compositing this effect over the default cube. Some tips:

- I used a clouds texture for the noise. The default noise texture didn't want to get scaled properly
- *Add*ing the effect was not such a good idea. *Mix* works better
- The clouds texture needs a color ramp to increase the contrast
- Blurring the texture (after the coloramp) can improve the result
- You should use multiple effect textures with different size and strength or use the one texture multiple times
- Animation can be done by creating an offset vector with the time input and some love
- If you use multiple textures, animate them in different directions

**ANOTHER EDIT**

Here my node setup with the result in the backdrop: [image: Node setup]

I used the same texture three times, you can see its settings on the right. The combine RGBA node is just another way to input the scale vector so that you can see its values. Do not use transform/scale nodes instead because this will look bad if you are not scaling down enough. The texture on the bottom is the basic noise, it will also work alone without the others. The texture in the middle adds some really small noise. It is only stretched by factor 3. The noise setup at the top gives some of the bigger artifacts.

To animate it, put an RGBA node into the texture offset and animate it as usual.

Comment: It would help if you add images of the proposed node setup and maybe a sample image that shows the result

Comment: I wanted to add them but blender crashed before I could save it (never run SheepIt-Renderfarm and Blender at the same time on an old laptop! :D). Maybe I'll redo the thing and add screenshots

Comment: Could you add some screenshots plz?

Answer (score 3):

(To further elaborate on [@piegames' answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53081/1853)) Using a noise texture and re-sizing it on the X axis, and then mixing it with an image (or render Layer) on the compositor.

[image]
(Click on image to enlarge)

Then just animate the placement on the texture on the X axis and you'll get moving noise:

[image]