# Add animated "tv static" effect to object in animation?

Tags: animation, materials

Essentially, I want to animate a white noise/tv static effect on a shape for like a couple seconds.

How would i go about doing this? (I'm a blender noob)

Comment: Show us what you tried, explain how you failed. Add what renderer you are using (Internal, Cycles, etc)!

Comment: @Leander i have zero history to present, i've just started using blender and this was how I wanted to proceed with the project i had in mind haha! sorry

Comment: There is still: *Add what renderer you are using (Internal, Cycles, etc)?*

Comment: oh sorry, Cycles!

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53074/create-image-effect-in-cycles-as-fnaf-video-noise-effect/53081#53081

Comment: @srysry when someone asks you to add info to your question they mean [edit] the question, not just add a comment. Also do you want this on just one object, or the whole render?

Answer (score 7):

Just use any high frequency texture like a small scale *Voronoi*, *Noise* or similar, attached to your shader, like an *Emission* and then animate it.

In this example I use a *Voronoi* texture, set to *Cells* with a high scale value. Then just animate any parameters you like.

Easiest and most seamless would probably be animating the position of the texture. If the speed is higher than the animation frame rate it will just look like it is changing randomly.

Use a *Color Ramp* node to adjust coloring and intensity as desired.

[image]